# Употребление дефиса перед годом

Tags: орфография

Хотелось бы прояснить следующий вопрос: как правильно употреблять дефис перед годом в названиях событий?

...в проекте знаменитой Олимпиады в Сочи-2014 (что мне кажется в корне неправильно)

...в проекте знаменитой Олимпиады в Сочи 2014...

...в проекте знаменитой Олимпиады-2014 в Сочи...

Или здесь перед годом везде нужно среднее тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если год входит в составное название, как например: ***Олимпида-2014***, тогда употребление дефиса корректно. Если же имеется в виду год проведения Олимпиады, например:  "***в проекте знаменитой Олимпиады в Сочи, в 2014 году...",*** тогда нужна запятая. Т.к. даты отделяются запятой.
Возможен и такой вариант оформления: ***в проекте знаменитой Олимпиады 2014 г** ., **в Сочи...***

Comment: Т. е. употребляется дефис и третий вариант корректен? А можно ли использовать второй вариант - без дефиса и без обозначения года? Вроде такое тоже встречала...

Comment: Тритий вариант этот: в проекте знаменитой Олимпиады 2014 г. в Сочи...?

Comment: Нет, я говорила о своих вариантах: в проекте знаменитой Олимпиады-2014 в Сочи.

Comment: Да, возможно, если 2014 входит в составное название: Олимпида-2014.

Comment: Спасибо большое!